# Multivariate Taylor expansion in Epanechnikov's paper

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, estimation, density-function, parameter-estimation

I'm trying to understand Epanechnikov's paper on nonparametric density estimation (https://search.proquest.com/docview/915574940?pq-origsite=gscholar&fromopenview=true) but I'm struggling with one of the equations he writes.

When he computes the "bias"-term $E[\Delta f_n(x_1,...,x_k)] = E[f_n(x_1,...,x_k)-f(x_1,...,x_k)]$ he obtains the asymptotic expression 
$$E[\Delta f_n(x_1,...,x_k)] \sim \frac12 \sum_{l = 1}^k \frac{\partial^2f(x_1,..,x_k)}{\partial x_l^2}h_l^2(n)$$  by taking the Taylor expansion of $f(x_1+h_1y_1,...,x_k+h_ky_k)$ around the point $(x_1,...,x_k)$.

But when I tried to verify the computation, I get the mixed partial derivatives $\frac12 \sum_{l = 1}^k\sum_{j = 1}^k \frac{\partial^2f(x_1,..,x_k)}{\partial x_l \partial x_j}h_l(n)h_j(n).$ Could anybody tell me what I am overlooking?

And also, I'm not quite sure what happens to the terms, where we take the first partial derivative (i.e. $- \sum_{l = 1}^k h_l(n)y_l \partial f(x_1,...,x_k)/\partial x_l$). Could anyone tell me what happens there?

Thank you. :-)

Comment: I can't read the paper.  What do $y$ and $E$ mean in this context.  Perhaps the missing cross terms vanish because of some special property of $E$ that you forgot to state?

Comment: @kimchilover Well the $E$ is the expectation $E[f(x_1,...,x_n)]=\int...\int_{\mathbb{R}^k} K(y_1,...,y_k) f(x_1+h_1 y_1,...,x_k+h_k y_k) dy_1...dy_k,$ where $K(y) =  K_1(y_1)...K_k(y_k)$ is a product kernel, and the $h_l(n)$ are bandwidth parameters converging to 0 as $n\to\infty$ and then $f_n$ is the KDE.

Comment: Looks like the cross terms vanish on integration: the product form of $K$  makes this happen.  Similarly, the first derivative terms.   The special unmentioned property is that $\int_{\mathbb R} y K_i(y)dy = 0$.

Comment: @kimchilover Ohhh, that property slipped my mind. Thank you so so much :)